# Docker for local development with multiple environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, microservices

I'm looking for using docker to emulate the minimum of our current cloud environment. We have about 10 services (each with your own MySQL8 database, redis, php-fpm and nginx). Currently they have a `docker-compose.yml` per repository, but they cant talk to each other, if I want to test a feature where a service needs to talk to another I'm out of luck.

My first approach was to create a `Dockerfile` per service (and run all together using a new `docker-compose.yml`), using Debian, but i didn't got too far, was able to install `nginx`, (`php-fpm` and dependencies), but when I got to the databases it got weird and I had a feeling that this isn't the right way of doing this.

Is there a way to one `docker-compose.yml` "include" each of `docker-compose.yml` from the services?
Is there a better approach to this? Or should I just keep with the `Dockerfile` and run them all on the same network using `docker-compose`?

Comment: You can configure `docker-compose` using [`external` networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network), i.e. project A is created with network A then project B is created and uses it's own network + the external network created by project A. Services from project B that are configured with the external network can communicate with the services running in project A.

Comment: If you do want to bring all the services up in a same network (assuming they are all configured using the default network) then you can use the [`-f` command-line option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) or the [`COMPOSE_FILE`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file) environment variable to include the services from all the `docker-compose.yml` files i.e.: `COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.a.yml:docker-compose.b.yml docker-compose up -d` however **beware** that this will work as an override if multiple projects specify a same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You can configure `docker-compose` using [`external` networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) to communicate with services from other projects or (depending on your project) use the [`-f` command-line option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/) / [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_file) to specify the path of the compose file(s) and bring all of the services up inside the same network.

---

#### Using external networks

Given the below `tree` with project `a` and `b`:

```
.
├── a
│   └── docker-compose.yml
└── b
    └── docker-compose.yml
```

Project `a`'s `docker-compose` sets a name for the default network:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx'
    container_name: 'nginx_a'
    expose:
    - '80'
networks:
  default:
    name: 'net_a'
```

And project `b` is configured to using the named network `net_b` and the pre-existing `net_a` external network:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx:
    image: 'nginx'
    container_name: 'nginx_b'
    expose:
    - '80'
    networks:
    - 'net_a'
    - 'default'
networks:
  default:
    name: 'net_b'
  net_a:
    external: true
```

... `exec`'ing into the `nginx_b` container we can reach the `nginx_a` container:

[image: external network service communication]

> **Note**: this is a minimalist example. The external network must exist before trying to bring up an environment that is configured with the pre-existing network. Rather than modifying the existing projects `docker-compose.yml` I'd suggest using [overrides](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).

The configuration gives the `nginx_b` container a foot inside both networks:

[image: compose services IP's]

#### Using the `-f` command-line option

Using the `-f` command-line option acts as an override. It will not work with the above compose files as both specify an `nginx` service (`docker-compose` will override / merge the first `nginx` service with the second).

Using the modified `docker-compose.yml` for project `a`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx_a:
    container_name: 'nginx_a'
    image: 'nginx'
    expose:
    - '80'
```

... and for project `b`:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  nginx_b:
    image: 'nginx'
    container_name: 'nginx_b'
    expose:
    - '80'
```

... we can bring both of the environments up inside the same network: `docker-compose -f a/docker-compose.yml:b/docker-compose.yml up -d`:

[image: -f command line option]

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have decided to use the -f method. The only issue that I found is that the mysql from service A crashes with service B's MySQL. With the erro message: `Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`

Comment: Are both services using a same named volume(?) looks like it in which case the first instance starts correctly and the second (mounting the same volume) can’t obtain the lock which is held by the first service.

Comment: Exactly, thats the issue. But shouldnt the volumes name be based on the service name?
One is called `sc_db` and the other `db`, both have:
`    volumes:
      - ./env/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: You’re using a bind-mount from the local file system, not named volumes. You could update your volumes mappings  for each of the db services to use a named volume or to use a different path on the host. i.e. replace `./env/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql` with `./db_a/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql` for one of the services and `./db_b/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql` so the services don’t try and mount the same directory.

Comment: Funny is that they are already in separeted folders. service A `docker-compose.yml` is in service_a/ folder, and the env is at `service_a/env`

Comment: Yes but the path `./env/mysql/data` is relative to wherever the `docker-compose up` is run iirc (I’d need to double check). The idea is there though, as long as those services aren’t mounting the same volume you should be good.

Comment: I just run a couple of tests, and the path `./env/mysql/data` is relative to the first `docker-compose.yml` file location (passed with -f argument), giving me the error: `build path ...\service_a\service_b\..  either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL`

Comment: I irl prefer using the external networks, much simpler imho but both are possible. To each their own.

Comment: Alright! I will use the external networks. Thank you!